# Authentication for single-page apps

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

**Background**

I am looking at the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Grant flow where a user is redirected to an authentication service and a JWT token is sent back a Single Page Application(SPA). The token is stored in a cookie or in local storage and, in the examples i have seen, the application will hide/show certain pages based on whether it can find the token in storage.

**Issue**

The problem is that in all the examples (official from service providers), i was able to manually add any random but properly formed token to the browser's local storage and got access to the 'secured' pages.

It was explained to me that you cannot validate the token in the SPA because that would require exposing the client secret and that you should validate the token on the API server. This means that you can 'hide' the pages but it is really easy to see them if someone wants to. Having said that you are unlikely to cause any real damage because any data retrieval or actions would need to go through the API server and the token should be validated there.

This is not really a vulnerability but the documentation and examples I have seen do not explicitly cover this nuance and i think that it could lead naive programmers (like myself) to think that some pages are completely secure when it is not strictly the case.

**Question**

It would be really appreciated if, someone who is better informed than i am, confirm that this is indeed how SPA authentication supposed to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am far from an expert, but I have played a bit in this space.  My impression is that you are correct, any showing/hiding of functionality based solely on the presence of a token is easily spoofed.  Your SPA could, of course, get into [verifying an access token](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/verify-access-token). 
But that may just make it a little more challenging to spoof.  If someone wants to fake the client into thinking it has a valid token, they can likely manipulate the client-side JS to do that.  Unfortunately that's the nature of client-side JS.  Much of the code can be manipulated in the browser.

Thus far this is speaking to protecting the user from seeing a UI/UX.  Most applications are only beneficial when they have data to populate their UI.  That's where the API access token strategy is still sound.  The server will verify the token and not give the client any data without it.

So while it's unfortunate that JS can be easily spoofed and manipulated to show things the developer would rather not make visible, this isn't typically a deal-breaker.  If you have some awesome UI feature that doesn't need data, and you need to secure access to that UI itself, this model may not be the greatest.

Comment: Thank you @BRass, it is really helpful to get confirmation that this is indeed how things work.