# Ionic Web Version Handling Disabled Elements

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a large ionic app which I deploy to Web as well as to mobile. However, one of the testing team notified me with an issue of disabled elements.
I have a lot of elements (buttons /checkboxes /inputs /etc) which can we disable depending on some roles/rules.

However, we are able to inspect element from the browser and remove the "disabled" property and the elements work as usual.

Now I can handle the logic from the typescript but I am not sure what's the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wondering about **fully** restricting access to features?  Client-side restrictions are always limited, as you found out, because users can manipulate the code in the browser.  Assuming your features trigger server-side interactions, then adding server-side access checking (in addition to client-side) is one option.

Similar question:
[Authentication for single-page apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463402/authentication-for-single-page-apps/51482517#51482517)

Comment: I was wondering what's the point of having disabled property client side if the user can remove it from the browser and all functionalities work as normal. But yeah I guess I have to add server side checking also

Comment: The disabled property is still very valid for the vast majority of users.  It just won't be completely foolproof against someone who has bad intentions and wants to find a way around that client-side restriction.